# Improve simple join

Tags: postgresql, performance, join

I have this simple join:

```
SELECT * 
FROM temp.mytemptable
JOIN sales USING (sale_id)
```

sales has an index (`sales_id`). `mytemptable` is just a temp table with 1 column (`sale_id`).

sales has million of rows, so it takes quite a while.

Here's the result of Analyze:

```
>   > Hash Join  (cost=531948.72..63776632.87 rows=1008571254 width=528)  
>     > Hash Cond: (sales.sales_id =
>     > mytemptable.sales_id)   ->  Append 
>     > (cost=0.00..32987546.53 rows=1008571254 width=529)
>     >         ->  Seq Scan on sales  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=1 width=597)
>     >         ->  Seq Scan on sales_y2018h2  (cost=0.00..6501510.24 rows=203409424 width=535)
>     >         ->  Seq Scan on sales_y2019h1  (cost=0.00..6567550.36 rows=188733936 width=533)
>     >         ->  Seq Scan on sales_y2019h2  (cost=0.00..7103620.60 rows=210640960 width=534)
>     >         ->  Seq Scan on sales_y2020h1  (cost=0.00..5243865.88 rows=164554288 width=535)
>     >         ->  Seq Scan on sales_y2020h2  (cost=0.00..6069904.52 rows=193076352 width=517)
>     >         ->  Seq Scan on sales_y2021h1  (cost=0.00..1501083.63 rows=48156163 width=497)
>     >         ->  Seq Scan on sales_y2021h2  (cost=0.00..11.30 rows=130 width=561)   ->  Hash  (cost=352639.43..352639.43
>     > rows=14344743 width=4)
>     >         ->  Seq Scan on mytemptable  (cost=0.00..352639.43 rows=14344743 width=4)
```

What would be the best way? adding an index could potentially speed things up? Do I need to add the index when creating the temp table or can I just create the index afterwards?

Thanks,

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers, format text)`** (_not_ just a "simple" explain) as  [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure you preserve the indention of the plan. Paste the text, then put `\`\`\`` on the line before the plan and on a line after the plan. Please also include complete `create index` statements for all indexes as well.

Comment: You are selecting all rows from both tables, no index is going to improve that

Comment: Have you tried creating an index taking a look at the execution plan? `explain analyse select * from ..`

Comment: I tried with an index but didn't improve the analyze plan much

Answer (score 0):

If `temp.mytemptable` is small, and `sale_id` is unique or at least pretty selective, then an index on `sales(sale_id)` would lead to a fast nested loop join.

If `temp.mytemptable` is larger, then an index won't help you, and you can improve performance by raising `work_mem` to get a hash join.

Answer (score 0):

Row counts:

```
result         1 008 571 254
sales          1 008 571 254
mytemptable       14 344 743
```

Since all rows from sales are returned in the result, table sales will have to be read completely, so an index on sales is not useful.

Note the name of column "sales_id" is misleading since that name implies it is the primary key of table "sales", but that cannot be true, because if it was the primary key, then the query would return at most the number of rows in mytemptable, and postgres would probably use an index on sales(sale_id).

Building the hash on mytemptable only accounts for 1% of the runtime, so adding an index on it wouldn't change much. It would probably not be used anyway, since a hash lookup is faster than an index lookup.

So... there's nothing you can do really to make this query faster. Since it is probably part of a larger job, maybe you can make that faster by using different queries.